# How to close PDF document that is used in Acrobat Reader ActiveX component from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, activex, acrobat

I have importated Acrobate Reader ActiveX component in my Delphi application and loaded PDF document with code:

```
var AA: TAcroPDF;

function GetFilePath(AFileName: String): String;
begin
  Result:=IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName))+AFileName;
end;

procedure TMainForm.Open2BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var FPath: String;
begin
  FPath:=GetFilePath('test.pdf');
  if not FileExists(FPath) then raise Exception.Create('No file');

  AA.LoadFile(FPath);
end;
```

But I can not unload PDF file from Acrobat ActiveX component. My use case requires that component unloads the file and shows gray rectangle upon the request from user. I have tried several code lines:

```
AA.Src:='';
AA.LoadFile('');
```

But file stays loaded all the time. I can successfully call the load of another file, but I can not find the way to unload the file.

I am using Delphi 2009, but I guess that my question applies to any version.

**Question update and suggestion of hack as a solution**:

I managed to adapt the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37889375/1375882 as for the close:

```
procedure TMainForm.Close1BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ref : Integer;
begin
  if Assigned(AA) then begin
    Ref:=AA.ControlInterface._AddRef;
    AA.Src:='';
    AA.Free;
    AA:=Nil;
  end;
end;
```

And accordingly I am checking `if Assigned(AA)` in `FormClose` as well. This works perfectly for me as far as I can see. But this seems to be no clean solution that was intended by Acrobat Reader?

**Bad consequences of the suggested hack/solution**:

No dark-gray rectangle remains on the form after onloading Acrobat Reader component in the suggested way and the subsequent call of anothes `LoadFile(...)` fails with AV, of course.

Comment: Try `LoadFile` (or assign src) with any non-blank string (`'x'`)

Comment: Thx @BrakNicku, this really solved the problem.